# Issue with Angular 7 video streaming from blob (flaky)

Tags: angular, html, video, video-streaming, blob

I'm developing an offline app that has a stored video in indexeddb and i'm generating a url from the blob that is stored:

```
const videoBlob = await this.storage.get<Blob>('some-video');
const url = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
```

Then I show the video in my component:

```
this.videoUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
```

Here's my html:

```
<div id="container" *ngIf="videoUrl">
    <video [src]="videoUrl" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>
</div>
```

**The problem**

Sometimes when the video loads, the video show the first frame then stop streaming. Looking at network request, I see 206 range request for the file, but the video is not "downloading". If I hit F5, sometimes it starts to stream properly and I can see the range requests downloading.

This is a snapshot of my network tab on chrome when it doesn't work:
[image]

And this is a snapshot when it works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that the reason why the video wasn't autoplaying was because the video autoplay policy on chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

I fixed my code this way:

```
  let videoPlayer = document.querySelector('video');
  try {
    await videoPlayer.play();
  } catch (err) {
    this.logger.warn(`Couldn't play video with sound. Muting video and starting it.`, err);
    videoPlayer.muted = true;
    await videoPlayer.play();
  }
```

My player is going to run in kiosk and this should'nt be an issue at that point. I think I got a low engagement because I kept refreshing the page. This chrome page did help find the low engagement rating: chrome://media-engagement/